# Field Service: correct way to cancel a BookableResourceBooking via SDK/API?

Tags: dynamics-crm

The BookableResourceBooking entity is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/bookableresourcebooking

I'd like to able to cancel a booking but I can't seem to find any SDK or API docs that explain how to do so. Would changing the [bookingstatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/bookableresourcebooking#BKMK_BookingStatus) value to "canceled" be sufficient to cancel a booking? Where would I input the reason code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SDK as well as API.

When you see Bookable Resource Booking in CRM, you can see Deactivate button. Clicking on it will deactivte the Bookable Resource Booking.

Now there is one more clean way to manage data, you can set Booking status to cancelled and then deactivate record in this way you can capture complete data as why Bookable Resource Booking record is cancelled/deactivated.

```
var entity = {};
entity["bookingstatus@odata.bind"] = "/bookingstatuses(bbda588b-013a-eb11-a813-000d3a25bbe9)"; /* cancelled booking status ID*/
entity.statecode = 1; /*Inactive*/
entity.statuscode = 2; /*Inactive*/

Xrm.WebApi.online.updateRecord("bookableresourcebooking", "bbda588b-013a-eb11-a813-000d3a25bbe9", entity).then(
    function success(result) {
        var updatedEntityId = result.id;
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Will try this out and see how it works!